# bumblebee + wine + directx9 not working

Tags: directx-9, wine

I'm trying to run dxdiag or any other DX9 game from bumblebee+wine and no luck. These games works well without bumblebee in integrated graphic card. And `no wine` soft works well with bumblebee.

**primusrun**

```
$ primusrun bash
$ wine dxdiag
primus: warning: recreating incompatible pbuffer
primus: warning: recreating incompatible pbuffer
$
```

syslog output:

```
rtkit-daemon[2489]: Successfully made thread 23036 of process 23036 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 3.
rtkit-daemon[2489]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
kernel: [147774.078061] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
kernel: [147774.221739] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
kernel: [147774.245670] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none
kernel: [147774.245900] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:26:46 PDT 2013
acpid: client 23009[0:1002] has disconnected
acpid: client 23009[0:1002] has disconnected
acpid: client connected from 23066[0:1002]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
acpid: client connected from 23066[0:1002]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
bumblebeed[11391]: [XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
rtkit-daemon[2489]: Successfully made thread 23071 of process 23033 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 2.
rtkit-daemon[2489]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
kernel: [147778.018119] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
kernel: [147778.030858] pci 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D0
kernel: [147778.030896] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3cold
```

**optirun** has similar result:

```
$ optirun bash
$ wine dxdiag
[VGL] NOTICE: Pixel format of 2D X server does not match pixel format of
[VGL]    Pbuffer.  Disabling PBO readback.
$
```

The syslog has the same error with optirun:

```
bumblebeed[11391]: [XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
```

Any help? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help, but try installing the primus-libs-ia32 package, it may be a 32 bit application you're trying to run (if you're on a 64 bit system, this could be the problem).